# How to configure Google Tag Manager to track link clicks on the same page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a single page website set up with internal links - I want to track these links and all other clicks that occur on my page, for example:

website.com/#link-to-here

Then further down I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="link-to-here"></div>
```

So when clicked the viewport changes to view that particular id but stays on the same page.

I am trying to set up the auto event listener - which seems to work but only tracks the one link I have to another page on the website(the rest is on the same page).

I have set up Analytics Universal, tag manager and all of my page views are working and in the live view.

I followed various tutorials and in Tag Manager I currently have 3 tags set up:

- Universal Analytics with a firing rule for 'all pages' - no conditions
- Link Click Listener with 2 firing rules 'all clicks' which has a condition of `{{event}}` equals `gtm.click` then the condition 'all pages' with the condition `{{url}}` matches RegEx `.*`
- UA event on internal links with the firing rule 'Internal Link Click' with again 2 conditions `{{event}}` contains `gtm.linkClick` and also `{{url}}` contains spectrospective (this is part of the URL). I figured i wouldn't be sure if their would be www. or not so this might eliminate any variances because the URL will always contain spectrospective - although this is probably where I went wrong.

Comment: Be sure that every time you click on any element you want to track the gtm.linkClick even is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your link click listener only needs to fire with the rule "all pages".

If this event is only for tracking internal link clicks, then perhaps just change the {{url}} part to {{hostname}} (the hostname is a part of the url), so that you don't need to check the entire url. This probably won't happen, but you could get a link like http://www.example.com/spectrospective, in which case the name "spectrospective" is in the url, but it's not an internal link, and your event would fire.